# How to get field as suggestion in SQL server using logic apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

This is my logic app workflow,

1. To get EDI 850 message as input for http trigger
2. Decode x12 message.
3. Transform xml
4. SQL server to insert data into the on-prem SQL database. while inserting data it doesn't shows POLineNumber field as suggestion it shows like GS01,SE01 as input suggestion. i'm using transform xml output for inserting the data into the table.

And my transform xml sample single field output as 1.

I would like to insert data into sql table. when i select table i want to  get that particular field as suggestion in insert row of sql server but it shows the segment of EDI 850 message like GS01, SE01, etc. i need as POLineNumber.

for an example when i use parse json in another logic app workflow for other business scenario it shows suggestion as account. for more clarification as shown in the below image
[enter image description here][1]

So for xml output i get suggestion as 
[enter image description here][1]

But i need as shown in the example flow image.

What component or how to get particular field in insert row of sql server. please fix the issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The suggested fields are informed by the decode component and are headers of full EDI 850 Interchange (GS, ST, ...). Also the component suggested you the "GoodMessages" and "BadMessages" collection to iterate.

Those fields (POLineNumber, ...) are of each item of GoodMessages, not from decode component.

You can validate the XML of each item and then you will get the suggested fields.